# assign an enum value (a const type) to a struct member that is a pointer

Tags: go, pointers, struct

For a test, with an unmarshalling function I received a `unit` variable, having a struct `Unit` for structure:

```golang
type Unit struct {
    ID           string            `json:"ID"`
    Name         *string           `json:"name"`
    CategoryCode *UnitCategoryCode `json:"categoryCode"`
    ... // and a lot of others
}
```

It is valued that way: `{ID: something, Name: something, CategoryCode: nil}`. It's the test case.

To continue my test, I would like to assign something to `CategoryCode`. A value that CategoryCode knows (under a `d` named import) as `AdministrativeUnit`

If I do a:

```golang
*unit.CategoryCode = d.AdministrativeUnit
```

It compiles, but do a nil panic, because of course `unit.CategoryCode` is nil:
`*(unit.CategoryCode)` has no sense.

but:

```golang
unit.CategoryCode = d.AdministrativeUnit
```

doesn't compile. type `(UnitCategoryCode)` against `(*UnitCategoryCode)`

```golang
unit->CategoryCode = &d.AdministrativeUnit
```

doesn't exist

and

```golang
unit.CategoryCode = &d.AdministrativeUnit
```

doesn't want to take the address of `d.AdministrativeUnit` that is a const.

I surely need to use a new somewhere, here. But how?

Comment: You can't take the address of a constant (because they don't have one). You'll need to either store `CategoryCode` by value or declare `AdministrativeUnit` as a `var`.

Comment: Or assign `AdminstrativeUnit` to a variable and then assign the pointer to that variable to `unit.CategoryCode`.

Comment: Simplest is to use a reusable `func Ptr[T any](v T) *T { return &v }` helper function to obtain a pointer to any value. This should be a builtin function...